# Can't run server and tests without modifying imports

Tags: python, python-unittest, bottle, nose

I'm building a website with the bottle framework. I am using nosetests for my unit testing. However there is a problem I can't solve on my own.

I can't seem to find a way that allows me to run the tests without breaking my server. When I run my tests, I have to do relative imports for them to work, but they don't work when I start the server.

This is my folder structure:

```
├── service
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── application.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── response_header.py
│   ├── global_data_loader.py
│   ├── renderer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── header.py
│   │   ├── ....
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── test_application.py
│   │   ├── ....
```

Here is how I import so my server works:

```py
application.py --
from response_header import ResponseHeader
from global_data_loader import GlobalDataLoader
from renderer import Application
```

However, when I run nosetests, I get this message: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'response_header'`

So when I want nosetests to work, I have to change the imports to look like this:

```py
application.py --
from .response_header import ResponseHeader
from .global_data_loader import GlobalDataLoader
from .renderer import Application
```

Then my nosetests work, but when I want to start my server I get this message:

```
from .response_header import ResponseHeader
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have tried using sys.path.append in my tests, and it works, but I need a solution that doesn't involve PYTHONPATH or using os/sys

edit: i fixed it by moving my main.py I use to start the server to the root folder, above my service and tests module. now it works fine